# При запуске интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, случайные-числа, pil, pillow

При запуске, программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tk.py", line 29, in <module>
    display_result_n()
  File "tk.py", line 27, in display_result_n
    display_result(n)
TypeError: display_result() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Сценарий работы приложения:

1. Пользователь решает задание
2. Вылетает окно с результатом
3. Следующее задание

И так по кругу

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random
import difflib

base = [["pic.png", "-Ты говоришь по английски? -Да", "-Как тебя зовут? -Да"], ["pic2.png", "Лицо моего инвестора", "Когда я рассказываю ему про блокчейн"]]

start = 0

n = random.randint(0,1)

def display_result():
    if start == 1:
        if first.get() == base[n][1] and second.get() == base[n][2] or difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, base[n][1], first.get()).ratio() > 0.85 and difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, base[n][2], second.get()).ratio() > 0.85:
            messagebox.showinfo("Memes", "Правильно!")
            n = random.randint(0,1)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Memes", "Непраильно( Ответ: \n\n" + base[n][1]  + '\n\n' + base[n][2])
            n = random.randint(0,1)
    new_img = Image.open(base[n][0])
    new_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_img)
    label["image"] = new_photo
    label.image = new_photo

def display_result_n():
    display_result(n)

display_result_n()
start = 1

root = Tk()
root.title("Memes")

new_image_black = Image.new("RGB", (320, 320), (0, 0, 0))
new_image_black.save("black.png", "PNG")

image = Image.open(black.png)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="e")

first = StringVar()
second = StringVar()

first_label = Label(text="Первая строка:")
first_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

second_label = Label(text="Вторая строка:")
second_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

first_entry = Entry(textvariable=first)
first_entry.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

second_entry = Entry(textvariable=second)
second_entry.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

button = Button(text="Готово!", command=display_result_n)
button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=2, sticky="n")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Укажите в вопросе напишите что не так.

Comment: Тоже не понимаю, где ошибка. Два раза прочитал вопрос, но так и не понял, в чем проблема :/

Comment: При запуске вылетает ошибка. При надобности кину.

Comment: у вас, случаем, тот код в `tk.py` находится?

Comment: И где у вас в коде функция `display_result_n`, которая указана в ошибке?

Comment: Извиняюсь за задержку. 1. Да, в tk.py. 2. Это старая версия кода, ошибка новая. Завтра напишу новый код.

Comment: Всё, залил новый код.

Comment: Функцию вызываете вы так: `display_result(n)`, а объявлена она так `def display_result():`. Поэтому и ругается на аргумент